# Extension of an real, complex embedding

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$L/K$ be an extension of number fields.

Following description is from Gerald J.Janusz "Algebraic Number Fields" p.110.

> Let $\tau\colon K\to\mathbb{C}$ be an embedding (=ring homomorphism). Since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, we know from Galois theory that there are $g=[L:K]$ embeddings $\tau_i\colon L\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\tau_i|_K=\tau$. (The $\tau_i$ are distinct and no two can be conjugate (else they could not agree on $K$).)

I don't understand this. What does "Galois theory" indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the statement. It should say

Since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, we know from Galois theory that there are $g=[L:K]$ embeddings $\tau_i:{\color{red}L} \to \mathbb C$ such that $\tau_i|K=\tau$.

**What it means** Whenever when you  $K \hookrightarrow L$ an extension of number fields, then any embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb C$ can be extended to exactly $[L:K]$ embeddings of $L$ into $\mathbb C$.

**Foe example** consider any embedding of $K=\mathbb Q[\sqrt[3]{2}] $ into $\mathbb C$.

Take $L: Q[\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{2}]$. Then $[L:K]=2$, and there are exactly two extensions of the above embedding: one which takes $\sqrt{2} \to \sqrt{2}$ and the second one which takes $\sqrt{2} \to -\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: exactly, thank you. I edited.

Comment: @user682141 See the edit, is this clear?

Comment: Well, I figure out it is possible to imitate that way and solve this question if we represent $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha),L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ for some $\alpha\in K,\beta\in L$ by primitive element theorem. But can't we do this avoid using primitive element theorem? And more, does this also hold for general finite dimensional field extension $L/K$?

Comment: @user682141 You can do this the following way: Pick some $\alpha \in L \backslash K$. Prove the result for $K \subseteq K(\alpha)$.

Comment: Next, if $K(\alpha)=L$ you are done. If not, pick some $\beta \in L \backslash K(\alpha)$ and prove the result for $K(\alpha) \subset K(\alpha,\beta)$. Repeat and apply the towering lemma.

Comment: How is the case $K(\alpha)/K$ proved ?

Comment: @user682141 The extension map must take $\alpha$ into a root of the image of its minimal polynomial. Since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, the number of roots is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial, which in turn is equal to the degree $[K(\alpha):K]$.

Comment: Okay, it is surely true that "if the extension map exist," then it maps $\alpha$ into a root of the image of its minimal polynomial. 

First, existence of the extension holds. In fact, let $F$ be a prime field of $K$, there exist extension $\tilde{\tau}\colon\overline{F}\to\overline{F}$ of $\tau$  by well-known fact (using Zorn's lemma in the proof) then restriction this to $K(\alpha)$ is what we wanted (identifying map to $\mathbb{C}$ with map to $\overline{F}$).

Comment: Second, $\tilde{\tau}(K(\alpha))=\tau(K)(\tilde{\tau}(\alpha))$ and there exist $[K(\alpha):K]$ isomorphism $\tau(K)(\tilde{\tau}(\alpha))\cong\tau(K)(\beta_i)$ (where $\beta_i\in \mathbb{C}$ are roots of the image of the minimal polynomial). Now we compose $\tilde{\tau}$ and these isomorphisms, we have $[K(\alpha):K]$ extension of $\tau$ and these are all.

Comment: @user682141 I think you are overthinking it: If $P(X)=a_nX^n+...+a_1X+a_0$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and if $\beta$ is ANY root of $\tau(a_n)X^n+...+\tau(a_1)X+\tau(a_0)$ it is easy to argue that you can extend $\tau$ by setting $\tau(\alpha)=\beta$.

Comment: Just define $\bar{\tau}: K(X) \to \CC$ via $\bar{\tau}(a_nX^n+...+a_1X+a_0)=\tau(a_n)\beta^n+...+\tau(a_1)\beta+\tau(a_0)$, check that is homomorphism, and that $\ker(\bar{\tau})=<P>$. Apply the first isomorphism theorem and use that $K(X)/<P>$ is cannonically $K(\alpha)$. The composition of these two mappings is exactly what you need.

Comment: Ah yes, we can avoid using "well-known fact"(Zorn's lemma) by such a constructive way (moreover, my way had to assume $K/F$ is algebraic). I wonder you mistook $K[x]$ for $K(x)$,but this is no problem since $K[\alpha]=K(\alpha)$. Thank you for your kindness.